# How can I check against multiple values using a Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am currently using this syntax in my Django 1.1.2 template:

```
{% ifnotequal myvalue 'ABC' %}
```

However, I now need to check "myvalue" to see if it's "ABC" or "DEF". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest determining this equality in the view and passing it in the context back to the template. In the template, you would test the variable instead of `myvalue` to determine what to display.

Comment: Unfortunately, I would want an "OR" condition, not an "AND". I'm going to take your advice on determining equality outside of the template and then passing it downstream. Please update your comment to reflect that as the primary answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 4):

Django templates do support [some simple logic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatetag-if):

`{% if myvalue == 'ABC' or myvalue == 'DEF' %}`

**NOTE:**  This functionality was added in Django 1.2 (See comments for more info)

Comment: No luck. I receive this error: 'if' statement improperly formatted

Comment: Yeah, this won't work. Keep in mind I'm using Django 1.1.2: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#if

Comment: @Huuuze: The new-style `if` template tag @Izkata mentions was introduced in Django 1.2, which is why it doesn't work for you. You might want to look into upgrading, since 1.1.2 is getting a little long-in-the-tooth anyways.

Comment: @Chris Pratt -- I agree, unfortunately, that's not an option.

Comment: @Huuuze Sorry, I missed that part.  I will leave the answer up, though, for anyone else that may run across it.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using django 1.2 or higher you can use the [`in operator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#in-operator). Otherwise you can use your own templatetags in django ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/custom-template-tags/)).

Create the folder and file `templatetags/is_member.py` in your app-foler and save the file with the following content

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def is_member_of(element, list):
  return element in list
```

Now you can use the templatetag in your template as follows

```
{% load is_member %}
{% if element is_member_of ["ABC", "DEF"] %}
  show some stuff
{% endif %}
```

But if possible use the way of Furbeenator.

Comment: templatetags are always a fast, clean and smart solution

Comment: Or you can simply use [in operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#in-operator)

Comment: you are right, but the in operator does not exists before 1.2 and the question was about django 1.1.2. But I've edited my answer.